# Why doesn't derived templated class's function override the non-templated base class's pure virtual function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

```
#include <vector>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template<typename Bar>
class Cloud : public Base
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
    }
};

class Water
{
};

int main()
{
    Cloud<Water> cloud;
    std::vector<Base> stuff;
    stuff.push_back(cloud);
}
```

The above shown code fails with the following on MSVC 14.1:

```
error C2259: 'Base': cannot instantiate abstract class
note: due to following members:
note: 'void Base::foo(void)': is abstract
```

Why does `Base::foo()` remain abstract even though `Cloud` implements it?
How would I implement this in a way that `Cloud` still derives from `Base`, overrides `foo()` and remains templated with `typename Bar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates here are just a distraction - they have nothing to do with your problem.

`std::vector<Base>` contains `Base` *objects*, not references, so if you try to add any derived instance to it, it will try to perform slicing, trying to instantiate a `Base` from the passed `cloud`. This, however, besides not being what you probably intended, is not possible, since a straight `Base` object cannot exist due to `Base` being an abstract class.

Most probably what you wanted was to push your object in the vector while still keeping the polymorphic behavior. To this end, you have to have a vector of *pointers* to the base class, and push pointers to the elements - most probably allocated on the heap, and with some mean of handling their lifetime. A simple (albeit possibly not optimal) solution may be having a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>` and push objects allocated with `std::make_shared`.

Comment: Thank you for the nicely explained answer! Keeping the polymorphic behaviour was definitely what I had intended. I decided to use `std::unique_ptr` instead as I don't need reference counting.

Comment: @tambre In that case, you need to give `Base` a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 4):

The function is a red herring: `std::vector<Base>` is a vector of `Base` objects, hence `push_back` tries to construct a `Base` from your `Cloud<Water>`.

Use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>` instead.

Comment: Or a `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Base>>` if you don't like pointers.

Comment: @Rakete1111 why would you not like pointers? They're nice with pickles. Joke aside, a `std::reference_wrapper<Base>` would not have the same ownership semantics as `std::unique_ptr<Base>` or `Base`.

Comment: True, didn't think of that. I was just putting it out there :)